# Get the last element from a std::vector

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In the following example, I would like to get an element from my vector. But I don't understand the error:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


using namespace std;

class Foo{
    virtual int end() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo{
    int end(){
        return 0;
    }
};


int main(){
    vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> a;
    a.push_back(make_shared<Bar>());
    shared_ptr<Foo> b = a.pop_back();
}
```

Here the error:

```
 g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:21:35: error: conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<Foo>’ requested
   21 |     shared_ptr<Foo> b = a.pop_back();
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

Comment: what does `pop_back` return? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back

Comment: You probably want to use `back` function - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back.

Comment: It is less about `shared_ptr` than solely about `vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed confusing. As said [kiner_shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4688321/kiner-shah) in his comment. You don't want to use `pop_back`

```
int main(){
    vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> a;
    a.push_back(make_shared<Bar>());
    shared_ptr<Foo> b = a.back();
}
```

The `pop_back` method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Find the last element from std::vector - 
**back()** - *access the last element*

```
int main(){
vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> a;
a.push_back(make_shared<Bar>());
shared_ptr<Foo> b = a.back();}
```

don't be use **a.pop_back()** *which is use for delete the last element in the std::vector.*

Comment: Both can be combined!

Comment: How is this any different than the answer posted 7 hours ago?